# I am trying to create a drop down menu but it not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I am hopping some one can help me with my issue !  I am quite new at coding so I might have missed something obvious but I am trying to integrate a dropdown menu from `'https://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/fcaDw'`
And after a copy past from the source code the drop down part is not working!
Does any any one know what is wrong?

Comment: it would be helpful to add some code, what have you tried so that other members can help you out

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: @Amelia Without the source code with the issue, useful advice will be difficult!

Answer (score -2):

use the tag

  and the list
- to add your required fields in dropdown then close the

tag

Comment: use ul tag and create li tag for required dropdown fields and close the ul tag

Comment: did you copy the css in SaaS file?